# How can I have Release variables with runtime substitution from other variables

Tags: azure-devops

I am trying to create a simple Runtime Variable in my Release Pipeline that carries the BuildNumber of the Triggering Artifact.

I tried adding a variable called `alias` and in the value column I wrote `$(Release.TriggeringArtifact.Alias)` And I set the `Settable at Release Time` to true.

Then I added another variable called BuildNumber and I wrote this in the value column: `$(Release.Artifacts{alias}.BuildNumber}` and set the `Settable at Release Time` to true.

I have a powershell task that Echoes the value of my variable BuildNumber. I was expecting the build number that was assigned to my artifact, but what I see is the git repository's name instead.

How can I have release time variables with pre-defined variables substituted in them?

Comment: Hi @fahadash. Is there any update about this ticket? Feel free to let me know if the answer could give you some help. Just a remind of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is to use [nested variable which is not supported](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/issues/5093):

> Thanks for your patience on this. I checked with the product team and there are places where variables will expand when nested, and the behavior will be slightly different if you specify variables with macro syntax (example: $(var)). However, this is not an officially supported feature and their recommendation is to not document macro variables as expanding recursively.
>
> If you would like to reach out the product team directly, please post in the Azure DevOps Developer Community. The product team actively monitors that space.

You can also vote on this on [developer community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/910272/nested-variables-are-not-yet-supported-in-the-buil.html)